# Fetching Double Value from SQLite in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, type-conversion, nsdate

Though it may seems very simple, I am trying hours on this.

Hello, everyone, I am storing double value in a SQLite Database in iPad application.

[image: SQLite Database image for field containing Double values]

I am fetching all the records using simple "Select * from tableName" query.

then I am converting this patient_dos value to double.

But this is what it prints when I display content of the first patient dictionary.

```
"patient_dos" = "1461561219160.408936";
```

and this below is the value I get after converting this value in to double variable using following conversion method.

```
double p_dos = [[dict objectForKey:@"patient_dos"] doubleValue];
```

Result is

```
Printing description of p_dos:
(double) p_dos = 1461561767624.27
```

My main concern is to match this double, It is actually a Timestamp, of the Day when patient admitted without HH:MM:SS information.

Update: 
[image: Added data type Image.]

Comment: Show the actual code that reads the value from the DB.

Comment: as I said, I am fetching data from Simple Select * from tableName query, then When I print the array returned by the query, it prints inconsistent value for "patient_dos" field.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert that string (which you get from database) into double like,

```
NSString *str = @"1461561219160.408936";

double fl = [str doubleValue];

NSLog(@"double vvalue is : %f",fl);
```

this is printing exact `1461561219160.408936` in my console

Comment: I am getting wrong double from SQLite DB itself, if I get correct value exactly what  I have in DB then conversion is the second step.

Comment: then change sqlite datatype `text to `double`. means don't store it as string store as double and retrieve as double.

Comment: The field is already a double type, in SQLite db itself, updated Image in original question.

Comment: then why are you converting it in double when fetch from database? keep it as it is!!